# Is it possible to Html.Hidden a text by its id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to @Html.Hidden a text value by id?

In the next example someText changes in JS.

```
<div id="someText">1</div>
```

I would like to add hidden value that will get the div's text, is it possible?

For example:

```
@Html.Hidden("Position", GetTextById("#someText"))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  What is the expected output?

Comment: @Amy I added an example, does it helps?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for Javascript and the DOM.

Comment: If you want to do this server-side, put the text of the div in a variable and reference it from both places: `@{ string position = "1"; }` `<div>@position</div>` `@Html.Hidden("Position", position)`

Comment: How would like to trigger the text to save inside Position Hidden Field? For example, mouse click on div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can!

First, let's say you want to add the hidden value inside your html body... just append the whole thing using jQuery:

```
$(body).append('@Html.Hidden("Position",' + $("#someText").val() + ')');
```

Given that, if your goal is just to hide the value, you could do:

```
$("#someText").hide();
```

Regards,